# Limitations of JavaScript api on client side?

Tags: web3js, security, javascript

I notice that the [Ethereum Javascript API](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API) allows the development of client side web based apps. Are their limitations or security gotchas to be aware of when developing such an app? Parts of the API that are really meant for server side JavaScript such as nodejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you pointing to is the documentation for the v0.20.0 of web3.

The v1.0.26.beta is available now, which documentation is also available [here](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/)

beetween v0.20.0 and v1.0.beta many changes happened. One important is the implementation of the web3.eth.accounts part.

on v0.20 web3.eth.accounts retrieved only an array of the available accounts.

on v1.0.beta, the web3.eth.accounts retrieves a list of functions as described in the doc.

However as this version is a beta, many functions can be still missing, and many can be buggy.

There's no real limitations others than the one that are already described in the doc. However, you'll probably find some bugs using those libraries. If that happens feel free to open an issue on the project repo on Github.

Last point regarding the Web3 library : it's no specificaly intended to be used on client side or server side. You can use it for both. However if you want to make a complete decentralized app you'll need to use it strictly on the client side.

Comment: So in fact, there are more issues with creating the app server side? Thanks. Not sure what app I'll build first, probably start work on an ethereum module for https://blockpress.me, but only once I've got the steem based blogging module in a usable state.

Comment: There are no more issues, but i guess different considerations to take. The point was to point out the fact that you have a newer version available and raising some flags to warn that those tools are still in development and all the bugs probably not detected yet. 

On my own i had to dig a lot through docs, tutorials and stacks tickets to understand some bugs, some work arounds and some technical considerations. dApp development is still something very young and the easibility of those tools will get developped as time passes.

Comment: The link to readthedocs in your answer goes to a blank document, are you sure it is correct? It doesn't seem to have any useful information, just something about creating a readme.

Comment: my bad, i update my answer so you get the correct link. I'll c/c below too :

[Doc v1.0.0](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/)